# Seeking application to create offline timelines

Tags: offline, time-management, charts

I am looking for a downloadable (offline/installable) application that helps in creating a timeline. It should grow preferably from bottom to top, something similar to Facebooks timeline. I don't need necessarily to add pictures or other fancy stuff to it.

I would like to create a timeline holding personal events. So far I have been using Excel for this task, which became more and more inconvenient.

Open Source would be nice but I am also willing to pay for it. The applications I have found so far are all web-based or require some form of cloud service (Google Drive, etc.)

Software I have found so far, maybe this list can help others...

- [Timeline](http://thetimelineproj.sourceforge.net/) (Open Source)
- [Sutori](https://www.sutori.com) (Web Based)
- [MyHistro](http://www.myhistro.com) (Web Based)
- [OurStory](http://www.ourstory.com) (Web Based)
- [Timeline](https://timeline.knightlab.com) (Web Based)
- [Free-Timeline](http://free-timeline.com/) (Web Based)
- [Timeglider](https://timeglider.com) (Web based)
- [SmartDraw](https://www.smartdraw.com/timeline/) (Web based & Downloadable)
- [TimeToast](https://www.timetoast.com) (Web based)

Answer (score 0):

How about projectlibre? It is a project management software.

https://www.projectlibre.com/product/projectlibre-open-source